# How to access the request object inside a GraphQL resolver (using Apollo-Server-Express)

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js, graphql, graphql-js

I have a standard express server using GraphQL

```
const server = express();

server.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress({ schema }));
```

Question is: how can I access the `request` object inside a resolver? I want to check the JWT in some specific queries

Here is the imported schema:

```
const typeDefs = `
    type User {
        id: String,
        name: String,
        role: Int
    }
    type Query {
        user(id: String): User,
        users: [User]
    }
`;

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        user: (_, args, context, info) => users.find(u => u.id === args.id),
        users: (_, args, context, info) => users
    }
}

module.exports = makeExecutableSchema({typeDefs, resolvers});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The request object should be accessed through the context. You can modify the options passed to your graphqlExpress middleware to define your context, like this:

```
server.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress(req => ({
  schema,
  context: { user: req.user }
}))
```

I know `express-graphql` actually uses the request as the context if it's not defined in the options -- Apollo's middleware may very well behave the same way but that's unclear for the documentation.

Finally, the context is then available as the third parameter passed to your resolver function.